# Django + PostgreSQL - 1000 inserts/sec, how to speed up?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, cprofile

I did some diagnosis and found that on `htop`:

- `python save_to_db.py` takes 86% of the CPU
- `postgres: mydb mydb localhost idle in transaction` takes 16% of the CPU.

My code for `save_to_db.py` looks something like:

```
import datetime
import django
import os
import sys
import json
import itertools
import cProfile

# setting up standalone django environment
...

from django.db import transaction
from xxx.models import File

INPUT_FILE = "xxx"
with open("xxx", "r") as f:
    volume_name = f.read().strip()

def todate(seconds):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds)

@transaction.atomic
def batch_save_files(files, volume_name):
    for jf in files:
        metadata = files[jf]
        f = File(xxx=jf, yyy=todate(metadata[0]), zzz=todate(metadata[1]), vvv=metadata[2], www=volume_name)
        f.save()

with open(INPUT_FILE, "r") as f:
    dirdump = json.load(f)

timestamp = dirdump["curtime"]
files = {k : dirdump["files"][k] for k in list(dirdump["files"].keys())[:1000000]}

cProfile.run('batch_save_files(files, volume_name)')
```

And the respective cProfile dump(I only kept the ones with large cumtime):

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  881.336  881.336 <string>:1(<module>)
  1000000    5.325    0.000  844.553    0.001 base.py:655(save)
  1000000   14.574    0.000  834.125    0.001 base.py:732(save_base)
  1000000   10.108    0.000  800.494    0.001 base.py:795(_save_table)
  1000000    5.265    0.000  720.608    0.001 base.py:847(_do_update)
  1000000    4.522    0.000  446.781    0.000 compiler.py:1038(execute_sql)
  1000000   23.669    0.000  196.273    0.000 compiler.py:1314(as_sql)
  1000000    7.473    0.000  458.064    0.000 compiler.py:1371(execute_sql)
        1    0.000    0.000  881.336  881.336 contextlib.py:49(inner)
  1000000    7.370    0.000   62.090    0.000 lookups.py:150(process_lhs)
  1000000    3.907    0.000   81.685    0.000 lookups.py:159(as_sql)
  1000000    3.251    0.000   44.679    0.000 lookups.py:74(process_lhs)
  1000000    3.594    0.000   53.745    0.000 manager.py:81(manager_method)
  1000000   19.855    0.000  106.487    0.000 query.py:1117(build_filter)
  1000000    5.523    0.000  161.104    0.000 query.py:1241(add_q)
  1000000   10.684    0.000  152.080    0.000 query.py:1258(_add_q)
  1000000    7.448    0.000  513.984    0.001 query.py:697(_update)
  1000000    2.221    0.000  201.359    0.000 query.py:831(filter)
  1000000    5.371    0.000  199.138    0.000 query.py:845(_filter_or_exclude)
        1    7.982    7.982  881.329  881.329 save_to_db.py:47(batch_save_files)
  1000000    1.834    0.000  204.064    0.000 utils.py:67(execute)
  1000000    3.099    0.000  202.231    0.000 utils.py:73(_execute_with_wrappers)
  1000000    4.306    0.000  199.131    0.000 utils.py:79(_execute)
  1000000   10.830    0.000  222.880    0.000 utils.py:97(execute)
      2/1    0.000    0.000  881.336  881.336 {built-in method builtins.exec}
  1000001  189.750    0.000  193.764    0.000 {method 'execute' of 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' objects}
```

Running `time python save_to_db.py` takes 14minutes, and roughly around 1000 inserts/sec. This is fairly slow.

My schema for `File` looks like:

```
xxx  TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
yyy  DATETIME
zzz  DATETIME
vvv  INTEGER
www  TEXT
```

I can't seem to figure out how to speed this process up. Is there some way of doing this that I'm not aware of? Currently I index everything, but I would be very surprised if that's the main bottleneck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [bulk create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).

```
objs = [
    File(
        xxx=jf,
        yyy=todate(metadata[0]),
        zzz=todate(metadata[1]),
        vvv=metadata[2],
        www=volume_name
    )
    for jf in files
]
filelist = File.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

Comment: Actually, I did this while you were answering and I ended up with a 2.5 minute insert. So 8000 inserts/sec. Thanks :)